# Pipe file to stdin and keep alive, waiting for new data

Tags: unix, pipe

A semi-newbie to UNIX piping, so apologies if I'm asking anything obvious here. I'm using a program called [CCExtractor](http://ccextractor.sourceforge.net) to grab the closed captions from a video file. It has the option to receive a file from stdin, and it works great if I do the following:

```
./ccextractor -stdin < myvideofile.wtv
```

However, I want to try using it "live" - as a video is recording, it'll transcribe the subtitles. From my understanding, `<` won't do that, as it'll stop as soon as it reaches the current end of the file. Following [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25537) on Stack Overflow, it seems like:

```
tail -c +1 -f myvideofile.wtv | ./ccextractor -stdin
```

should work - but it doesn't process any part of the video at all (it should, at least, work as well as the previous command and parse the existing data). I figured I'd take a step back and use a simple `cat`:

```
cat myvideofile.wtv | ./ccextractor -stdin
```

and that doesn't work either. I was of the belief that the first and third commands ought to be roughly equivalent, but that's obviously not the case. What are the differences, and how could I get this to work?

Comment: The `tail` method should work, but make sure whatever is writing to the video file is flushing it regularly.

Comment: In this case I'm actually using it with a complete file, just to prove the concept. That tail command *should* just pipe the whole file into `ccextractor`, right?

Comment: Correct.  Does `ccextractor` handle streaming data or does it buffer its output?

Comment: I'm not sure what would cause the difference though really. Your cat attempt eliminates any possibilities of flushing and blocking reads being a problem. Stdin will be a stream either way. Use strace on ccextractor to try and see what it's going in the pipe to case maybe?